# the correct Ruby version when opening a terminal

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, rvm

Each time I open a terminal my Ruby version is wrong. I am obliged to execute by hand the following command:

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

I read that RVM doesn't modify .bashrc or .bash_profile but I note that my .bashrc has at the end:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
```

Not only I didn't insert this myself but the path to rvm is wrong !
I changed by:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

I reopened a terminal but the Ruby version is always wrong !

Comment: The fact that rvm is in your /usr/local/ folder tells me that you installed RVM as root, at least at some point.  This is an atypical install.  You likely want to correct that and install RVM as your normal developing user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rvm does modify your .bash_profile / .bashrc -- that's one of its weaknesses. In particular, it adds (is supposed to add) this line to load rvm as a shell function:

```
# Load RVM into a shell session as a function
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I had a similar issue with the wrong ruby version running even after I changed the global default in rvm--ensuring this line was at the end of my .bash_profile fixed it. In any case, that line's supposed to be there for rvm to work properly.

Comment: I am not sure I consider that a weakness... where else are you supposed to indicate your desired modifications for your environment for your login.  Regardless, that will not fix his problem at all.  It doesn't address the location he installed RVM to.

Comment: It may not (but it may). Without knowing the details of his setup, I think the omission of that line from his bash_profile should be addressed, as that's critical for rvm's functioning. 

And to clarify, being loaded as a shell function is a weakness relative to rbenv, which doesn't have that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `.rvmrc` file in the root directory of your application.

It runs whatever is inside on opening the root direct, so I think you can just copy this

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

and things should be good.  You'll get a warning, but it's safe to ignore (or has been in my experience).  I think you might be better off going with this, which I've found helpful to keep rubies/gemsets straight across applications.

```
#.rvmrc
rvm [ruby]@[gemset] #for example rvm 2.0.0-p247@my_gemset
```

Why gemsets/rubies get switched/reset in the first place, I really don't know and it is annoying, but this seems to fix it.

read more [here](http://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup it could not be loading for several reasons.

For instance, when you open a shell (depending on the OS distribution) bash files are read in various orders, although here is what the standard looks like: ( I believe Ubuntu is slightly different so you might want to check if thats your distro).

```
# for interactive login shells (when you login to a terminal)
/etc/profile
/home/<user>/.bash_profile
/home/<user>/.bash_login # if there is no .bash_profile
/home/<user>/.profile # if there is no .bash_login
# for interactive non-login shells (i.e. opening up a new tab)
/etc/bash.bashrc
/home/<user>/.bashrc
```

What happens when you directly source your .bashrc? Does it then find rvm? If so, then its just a matter of making sure your .bash_profile sources .bashrc aka:

```
# in .bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

If this isn't the cause you could dive into the rvm documentation or switch to rbenv which IMHO is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

RVM should handle this automatically but this code is wrong.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

RVM's path should be first. Your bash is acting as you *wish* actually. It uses the 'system wide' ruby first because you tell your shell to do so. Change this to:

```
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH
```

then `source ~/.bashrc` and it will work as you wish, calling `rvm` ruby when you login.