# Ruby Version Different Depending on Terminal Tab

Tags: ruby, terminal

This question seems to happen a lot ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691448/terminal-and-control-panel-shows-different-version-of-ruby), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027250/different-ruby-versions-showing-in-terminal-windows), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774091/the-correct-ruby-version-when-opening-a-terminal)), but never with a successful answer.

I have ruby 2.5.0 installed correctly and have verified it with `ruby -v`.  However, when I open a new Terminal tab, it defaults me back to ruby 2.3.3p222 for some reason.  I have `ruby '~> 2.5.0'` in my gemfile, if it helps.

Does anyone know how this is happening?

Comment: How did you install ruby (rvm, rbenv, brew, RubyInstaller)? What platform are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RVM can read the `.ruby-version` file on the root of your project folder.

```
echo 2.5.0 > .ruby-version
```

Open a new terminal and check the Ruby version.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I'm still not sure why, but thank you!

Comment: This `.ruby-version` file is like a default place where some services and applications look for your target version. Google Cloud Platform, Heroku, RBenv, RVM and some other services use this file.

Answer (score 0):

A new tab opens a new shell, which re-reads your shell's initialization files.  It doesn't start with the environment variables which happen to be set in the currently-active tab.

Comment: So how do I get it to update the initialization files to show the correct version of Ruby?

Comment: Perhaps you have the two versions of Ruby installed in different directories, but one happens to be either absent from `PATH` or later in `PATH` than the older one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rbenv, you can set your global ruby by:

```
rbenv global 2.5.0
```

Pretty much the same thing for rvm:

```
rvm --default use 2.5.0
```